# html, php: Need suggestions how simplified the working html code

Tags: php, html, function, structure, echo

I want to write HTML as php functions

for example

```
function input_textarea($inputid, $lablevalue, $materializeicon){ 
    echo '
        <div class="input-field">
            <textarea id="'.$inputid.'" name="'.$inputid.'" dir="rtl" class="materialize-textarea right-align" cols="20" rows="20"></textarea>
            <label for="'.$inputid.'">'.$lablevalue.'</label>
            <i class="material-icons prefix right">'.$materializeicon.'</i>
        </div>  
        ';
}//end echo
```

I run it on several ducuments as:

```
<?php input_textarea('description', 'Put item desctiption', 'message') ?>
```

Still asking ho to improve, or what the better way to do so?

another example that separate the area to 2 parts (in Materialize)

```
function row2cols_start($leftside){
            
    echo '
       <div class="row"><!-- row start//-->
        <div class="col s'.$leftside.'">';
}

function row2cols_middle($leftside){
    $rightside=12-$leftside;
    echo '
        </div>
        <div class="col s'.$rightside.' ">';
}

function row2cols_end($rightside){echo '
        </div> 
        </div><!-- row end//-->';
}
```

executed by

```
<?php row2cols_start(8); ?>
<div><!-- row start//-->
text1
</div><?php row2cols_middle(8); ?>
<div><!-- row middle//--> 
text2
</div><?php row2cols_end(8); ?>
<!-- page row end//-->
```

Its looks better but it still complicate to remember all the you set

I need some ideas how to simplify it

Comment: Stop! You are doing this wrong. Read about templates

Comment: is there some way to simplify it ?

Comment: @legopart Yes, templates.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your templates in PHP is kind of a bad practice. You should try to use a template engine like [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) (one of the most common template engines for PHP, but there are many other).

With twig you can use macros for repeatedly used fragments. There are also many other features like escaping of values, template hierarchy, includes,… which may even eliminate the need to put everything in separate functions.

Your template could look like this:

```
{% extends "layout_base.html.twig" %}
{% import "forms.html" as forms %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col s8">
            text 1
        </div>
        <div class="col s8">
            {{ forms.textarea('description', 'Put item desctiption', 'message') }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This would enhance the readability of your templates, and prevents putting business logic in your templates.

Comment: this language it too complicated to me at this point :(, i having really issue to install things on the server (I dont know how)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use only PHP, have a look at the [alternate syntax for control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and [short tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) which are really useful for templates:

```php
<div class="col s8">
    <?php if(!empty($user)): ?>
        Welcome <?= $user ?>!
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="col s8">
    <?= input_textarea('description', 'Put item desctiption', 'message') ?>
</div>
```

tl;dr: Short tags are a handy way to write `<?php echo`, the alternate syntax for control structures removes a lot of curly braces.